# How do I make an element hide behind the border?

Tags: html, css

This is my code.

I'm trying to create a spinner loader that has a line passing through the circle.

```css
.line {
  width: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  animation: myfirst 0.75s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
    right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0%   {background: blue; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
  100% {background: blue; left: 120px; top: 0px;}
}

.rotate {
  border: 64px solid #363636;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1.36s linear infinite;
  position: relative; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate"><div class="line"></div></div>
```

I've tried to position absolute and relative and z-index but they do not work.

Any tips or help is very appreciated <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `::before` element to cover the line

```css
.line {
  width: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  animation: myfirst 0.75s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: blue;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue;
    left: 120px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}

.rotate {
  width: 120px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 64px #363636;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1.36s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.rotate::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: -64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 64px #363636;
  z-index: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```